# СПП с однородными придаточными

Tags: спп

> На всем, на всем, что было и не было вокруг, царило беспросветное отчуждение, неземная пустынность, в которой царапалась слабеющей лапой, источившимся когтем неведомая, дух испускающая тварь(,) да резко пронзало оцепенелую мглу краткими щелчками и старческим хрустом, похожим на остатный чахоточный кашель, переходящий в чуть слышный шелест отлетающей души.

Здравствуйте, подскажите, пожалуйста, почему ставится взятая мной в скобки запятая, ведь по идее — союз *да* соединяет два придаточных, в одном из которых пропущено союзное слово? Может ли это быть опечаткой в книге?

Вот правило:

*Между однородными придаточными частями сложноподчиненного предложения, связанными неповторяющимися союзами (соединительными или разделительными) запятая не ставится.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Степан Попов:*
>   ...пронзало относится к *отчуждение* (что логично), а не к *пустынность.*

Не соглашусь с Вами. Галина сказала уже, что это самостоятельное предложение: *царило отчуждение, пустынность да резко пронзало (тем и сем)...* Никакой не нахожу логики, согласно которой *пронзало* можно отнести к *отчуждению.*

> *Лиза Запорожец:*
>   Почему же нельзя назвать данное предложение сложноподчинённым с однородными придаточными, если после "да" спокойно можно вставить союз?

Формально вставить можно, это может быть предложение с однородными придаточными, но представить себе *отчуждение* и *пустынность,* в которых чем-то пронзало *сложнее,* чем представить *пронзающее просто на всём вокруг.* *И вообще, на мой взгляд, логика должна быть другой: **раз стоит запятая, делаем вывод, что придаточное со "в которой" закрывается перед "да"**. Не стоит думать, а не ошибся ли автор, закрыв придаточное; может, он забыл объединить его с другим потенциальным придаточным и ошибочно поставил запятую.* Всё возможно, но маловероятно, особенно в этом случае, в котором, как я уже заметил, фраза в таком виде (без запятой) становится совсем сложной для осмысления.

Answer (score 2):

Лизанька, да просто придаточное закрылось запятой!

*, **в которой царапалась** слабеющей лапой, источившимся когтем неведомая, дух испускающая **тварь**,*

подлежащее - тварь, сказуемое - царапалась (лапой, когтем).

---

Освободим предложение от красот:

На всём царило беспросветное отчуждение, неземная пустынность (ЗДЕСЬ ПРИДАТОЧНОЕ в двух запятых) да резко пронзало оцепенелую мглу (тем и сем)...

подлежащее - пустынность, отчуждение; сказуемые - царило, пронзало.

---

Можно прочитать по-другому: резко пронзало (тем-сем) - самостоятельное предложение, но смутившая Вас запятая по-любому нужна ввиду придаточного.

Comment: Галина, в этом предложении _отчуждение_ пронзало оцепенелую мглу щелчками или _тварь_?

Comment: Почему? Я ж написала СРАЗУ: ***Можно прочитать по-другому: резко пронзало (тем-сем) - самостоятельное предложение, но смутившая Вас запятая по-любому нужна ввиду придаточного.*** Я просто тип предложения не указала - неопределённо-личное? ***Мглу пронзало щелчками и хрустом***.

Comment: И вообще Астафьев захлёбывается нагнетающимися словами, на чей-то вкус - создаёт ***атмосфэру***...

Comment: Да, я все понял. Если бы я просто _пробежал_ это предложение глазами, то не заметил бы всей его _красоты_.

Comment: Стёпыч, серьёзно? КРАСОТЫ? Вау... Без ста грамм не одолеть!

Comment: Галина, там курсив)

Comment: Ога! Курсив означает, что ***атмосфэра***, которую ***о дайте, дайте мне!..***, адекватно друг с другом ***коррелируют***? Кароч: брат ты мне по разуму иль нет? О_о

Comment: На всем, на всем, что было и не было вокруг, царило беспросветное отчуждение, неземная пустынность, в которой царапалась слабеющей лапой, источившимся когтем неведомая, дух испускающая тварь да в которой резко пронзало оцепенелую мглу краткими щелчками и старческим хрустом, похожим на остатный чахоточный кашель, переходящий в чуть слышный шелест отлетающей души. Почему же нельзя назвать данное предложение сложноподчинённым с однородными придаточными, если после "да" спокойно можно вставить союз?

Comment: Лиза, я давно жгуче не люблю Астафьева. Зачем так мучить язык? Мне-читателю не удалось запихнуть хвост предложения внутрь придаточного.

Answer (score 1):

Попробую ответить попроще:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Это придаточное, в свою очередь, относится к *неземная **пустынность***, *в которой*...

Вы не можете вставить после *да* союзное слово *в которой* (***пустынность***, в которой *царапалась тварь* да (и) в которой *пронзало*), чтобы сделать эти предложения однородными, так как *пронзало* относится к *отчуждение* (что "логично"), а не к *пустынность*.

Comment: Я только не понимаю, как отчуждение что-то там пронзает, но это уже, как говорит Галина, "атмосфэра". Я могу быть не прав в своих рассуждениях, будьте осторожны с выбором.

Comment: Степан, сказуемое здесь "царило", потому что, как ни крути, только оно характеризует подлежащее.

Answer (score 1):

Это предложение является, очевидно, сложным. Если позадавать вопросы к его членам, можно определить его основы и построить схему. Будут такие обозначения: [ ] - главное предложение, ( ) - придаточное, { } - мой комментарий, относящийся к предшествующему слову. Вот так выглядит схема (на ней я не стал изображать обороты):

[ (что  {союзное слово} было и не было {сказуемое} ) , царило {сказумое} отчуждение, пустынность {однородные подлежащие} , ( в которой {союзное слово} царапалась {сказуемое} тварь {подлежащее} ] , да [ пронзало {сказумое} ] .

Во-первых, слово "пронзало" выражено безличным сказуемым в форме 3 лица единственного числа. Предложение с ним является самостоятельным, а не придаточным к первому (со сказуемым "царило"), т. к. между ними нет связи: второе предложение не относится к слову "на всем", в частности и от первого нельзя задать вопрос ко второму. Также союз "да" можно заменить на союз "и". Поэтому они имеют сочинительную связь и требуют запятой между ними.

Во-вторых, придаточное предложение с основой "царапалась тварь", относящееся к первому предложению, выделяется с двух сторон запятыми, и поэтому запятая снова ставится.